# PHP adding unwanted line break to ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, line-breaks

Why is PHP adding a line break to my simple AJAX result?  This couldn't be much easier.  Am I missing something?

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputEmail').change(function(){
        // Check to see if email exists
        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        //alert(email);
        $.ajax({
            url : "php/checkUserEmail.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {email: email},                
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(data === "exists"){
                    alert(data);                        
                }                    
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("ajax error");
            }
        });              
    });
});
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php 

include_once("db_connect.php");

// Catch results sent via $.post and assigns them to php variables.
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Check to see if email exists
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rowCnt = $result->num_rows;

if($rowCnt == 0){
    echo trim('new');
}else{
    echo trim('exists');
}
```

For whatever reason, my result data string is returned as /r/nexists, rather than just exists, and thus never gets into my if block, even if I only use == to evaluate the condition.  I tried adding the trim() function as you can see without result.  Your help is much appreciated as this has taken me hours of time for a stupid if condition.

Comment: If you run the PHP as a stand-alone does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: No It does not appear to.  I just created an index.php page with simple mysqli object and then my code (instead of incude(db_connect.php) )and it does not have line breaks added to the echo.

Comment: You can also trim on the client-side, `data.trim()` Also [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Tried to trim on client without result.  I should have to do that.  I don't like things that happen for no reason.  Thanks for helping

Comment: You're welcome @John - I just wanted to try it as a test to help us get there.

Comment: Your PHP script has a SQL injection vulnerability in it, and you'd be advised not to go live until that is fixed.

Comment: Please post the contents of db_connect.php

Comment: I'd replace `checkUserEmail.php` with nothing but a text value of `exists` and see if that fixes it. You can then start to add things back in if so.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is an "empty" space after or before the php question marks, those line-breaks are also represented as part of the response.

```
I mean here
<?php?>
And here
```

Comment: There is no space.  The code is as it appears above.

Comment: Just so you know I tried something, I did remove the trim() function.  I also removed all whitespace from the echo statement.  So it is now:  echo'exists';

Comment: Did you also check the `db_connect.php` file to make sure there is not a new line before `<?php`

Comment: Maybe you are not closing the php tag?, perhaps you're leaving a space there.

Comment: Got It.  Ok I tried that.  There was a space after my <?php but that also did not help.  Still returning /r/nexists with result.

Comment: Double checked db_connect and all other php files for spaces and closing php tag.  There were some spaces but removing them had no result.

Comment: Do you get the linebreak if you change your PHP/AJAX function to just print a basic string, ie 'hello' (with all of the same database-related code surrounding it)?

Comment: Are you saving your file in UTF8 encoding *without* BOM ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I still do not like or understand what is happening.  You should be able to return a simple string for a result.  Anyway, what I did was to just echo the number of rows returned from the DB to my ajax success function.  I then checked if the result was > 0 on the client and am finally in my IF block.  Here is what I did:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputEmail').change(function(){
        // Check to see if email exists
        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        //alert(email);
        $.ajax({
            url : "php/checkUserEmail.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {email: email},                
            success: function(data){                    
                console.log(data);
                if(data > 0){
                    console.log("HURRAY!  I'm in my IF");   
                }                    
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("ajax error");
            }
        });              
    });
});
```

Here is the PHP:

```
    // Catch results sent via $.post and assigns them to php variables.
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // Check to see if email exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $rowCnt = $result->num_rows;

    echo $rowCnt;
?>
```

This works, and is actually maybe alittle more elegant, but you should be able to return a string without issue.

John

Comment: This really isn't a solution though, we return text from PHP all of the time without the carriage feeds/line returns.

Comment: You are correct.  Not a solution to the problem described, just a different way to get where I am going.  Would still like to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I am trying to replicate now, but not having any luck.

Comment: OK.  I Just rewrote the code to pass a string again and now it is working fine.  There must have been some invisible encoded character or something before.  When I changed to return the integer instead of the string it worked also, but then upon rewriting server side if condition to return 'exists' or 'new' it now returns the string without a line break.  Not sure what was going on there, but I spend hours trying to figure it out. Ugg.